# How to prefetch scripts for another Domain?

Tags: javascript, html, prefetch

My goal is to fetch a Vendor.js file on my landing page

> [www.test.com](http://www.test.com)

The Vendor.js is for a larger page that you get navigated to after clicking a Link on the landing page.
You should get navigated to:

> bookings.test.com

Here it should load the vendor.js that should be prefetched on the Landing page. (load from cache)
But even if I prefetch it, it never works.
The vendor.js will always be fetched from the server by the "main application".

How can I fetch it from the Cache?

WHat I tried on my landing page

`<link rel="prefetch" href="https://bookings.test.com/vendor.js" as="script">`

Here it loads the script (at least in the network tab).
But as soon as I navigate to the main app, it will load the vendorjs again from the network but not the cache.

How do I access prefetched scripts from another domain?

Comment: If you are using Chrome dev tools to test this, make sure that the dev tools themselves aren't preventing the cached copy from being loaded. There's a `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` checkbox in the options.

Comment: @DBS Cache is enabled. 
But it works only on the same page. Not when navigating